# Python Scraping from JavaScript table on PGA Website

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I'm just getting into Python and have been working mostly with BeautifulSoup to scrape sports data from the web.  I have run into an issue with a table on the PGA website where it is generated by javascript, was hoping someone could walk me through the process in the context the specific website I am working with.  Here is a sample link "http://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/players/player.29745.tyler-aldridge.html/statistics" the tables are all of the player statistics tables. Thanks!

Comment: You can either use `selenium` instead of the headless browser (so that javascript executes and then you can parse the html) or you may try hitting the API that the javascript is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a web page uses JavaScript to build or get it's content, you are out of luck with tools that just download HTML from the web. You need something which is mimicking a web browser more thoroughly, and interpreting JavaScript. In other words, a so-called **headless browser**. There are some out there, even some with good Python integration. You may want to start your journey by searching for `PhantomJS` or `Selenium`. Once you've chosen the tool of your choice, you can let the browser do it's retrieving and rendering work and then browse the DOM in much a similar way than you did with `BeautifulSoup` on static pages.

I would, however, also a look at the Network tab of your browser's debugger first. Sometimes you can identify the `GET` which is actually getting the table data from the server. In this case it might be easier to `GET` the data yourself (e.g. via `requests`) than to employ complex technology to do it for you. It is also very likely that you get the information you want in plain `JSON` which will make it even simpler to use. The PGA site makes `GET`s hundreds of resources to build, but it will still be a good trade to browse thru them.

Comment: This is interesting, something I have briefly looked into on other sites, but never gained any traction.  It looks like that might be the way to go in this instance though, just need to dig around and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Ended up figuring out the JSON feeds.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript Engine to parse and run JavaScript code inside the page. There are a bunch of headless browsers that can help you

http://code.google.com/p/spynner/

http://phantomjs.org/

http://zombie.labnotes.org/

http://github.com/ryanpetrello/python-zombie

http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/

http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/

Also, consider using this:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Selenium-WebDriver makes direct calls to the browser using each browser’s native support for automation. How these direct calls are made, and the features they support depends on the browser you are using. Information on each ‘browser driver’ is provided later in this chapter.

For those familiar with Selenium-RC, this is quite different from what you are used to. Selenium-RC worked the same way for each supported browser. It ‘injected’ javascript functions into the browser when the browser was loaded and then used its javascript to drive the AUT within the browser. WebDriver does not use this technique. Again, it drives the browser directly using the browser’s built in support for automation.